# Enable left skip only on pages with section heading

Tags: sectioning, titlesec

I want to change the layout of pages which contain a `\section` heading (and also the `\tableofcontents`) so that the body text is over to the right-hand side of the page. Using `\leftskip` and `titlesec`  I have been able to get a layout that I like:

[image]

But how can I disable `leftskip` for subsequent pages that don't have a `\section` heading on them?

I don't want this on subsequent pages:

[image]

I want this:

[image]

Also I want the `tableofcontents` to use the `leftskip` - i.e. 'Contents' on the left-hand side and the contents info on the right. Currently it looks like this:

[image]

MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\leftskip=5.5cm
\titlespacing{\section}{0cm}{0cm}{-0.5cm}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\clearpage
\section{Section}
\noindent\blindtext[3]
\subsection{Subsection}
\blindtext

\end{document}
```

Additional info

- I am open to a solution that requires manually specifying the page break.
- New sections always start on a new page.
- The table of contents will probably only be one page long, but even if it was more than one page I want the content to be over to the right-hand side (i.e. it can have consistent formatting).

Comment: essentially this is not possible without  a lot of effort, you can not change the text width at an automatic page break as the linebreaking happens first, before the page break is known.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle What if the page break is forced manually? i.e. the body text on the page with the section heading fits onto one page and I am able to manually start a new page.

Comment: Then it is completely different (and easy) eg put all the settings of `\leftskip` in an environment and just use th environment on your section open pages, and define the environment to end with `\clearpage`  (this is how `landscape` from lscape package works, which is changing the text width for other reasons, but same issues)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Ok thanks, I added some additional info to my question in light of your comments.

Comment: `\newenvironment{sectionpage}{\leftskip=5.5cm}{\clearpage}` - I've come up with this solution which seems to work. Only problem is the `\leftskip` isn't being applied to the `\tableofcontents` when I enclose it in this environment. But perhaps that's a whole separate problem to tackle.